# How to change image folders and domain with mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have images like this - http://www.site1.com/upload/long/long/long/long-path/image.jpg
I need redirect all images in folder upload to another site and strip path.

Example site1.com/upload/long/long/long/long-path/image.jpg ---> site2.com/image.jpg

Mod_rewrite instructions I'm trying to construct look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/upload/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteRule (.+) site2.ru/$1 [QSA,R,L]
```

But this code dont strip long path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(.+)` captures the whole path. SInce you only want to match the filename, you need to write expressions like `^/upload/.+/([a-z]\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png))$` instead. Supplement the range *a-z* to include whatever characters can be in your filename.